# python sqlite3 table disappearing for no apparent reason

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a python sqlite3 db with a single table that for no obvious reason 'disappears' -- I guess it's getting dropped. The database file is still there, and does not seem to be 'corrupted': I can connect to it via CLI and execute basic operations on it:

```
sqlite> SELECT name FROM sqlite_schema WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name;
```

returns nothing. So far, it's only happening in dev, and only happens a few days after restart. There's very little traffic on the dev server, mostly just me testing the app.

**I'd welcome any ideas on how to debug this problem**. There are no errors in the logs that point to a *cause* of the table dropping. I've added some more verbose logging, but there's nothing that I can see happening that causes the table to drop. Just, at some point, it's gone, and I start getting `no such table` errors:

```
# Everything looking fine....
2023-03-07 17:14:43,039 139982591223616 - application INFO - Updating hash value for PID: 12933
2023-03-07 17:14:43,039 139982591223616 - application INFO - Connecting to: /some_path/mydatabase.db
2023-03-07 17:14:43,047 139982591223616 - application INFO - Connecting to: /some_path/mydatabase.db
2023-03-07 17:14:43,063 139982591223616 - application INFO - Got 7 cache items. This is 7 more than the previous set.
2023-03-07 17:14:43,064 139982591223616 - application INFO - Connecting to: /some_path/mydatabase.db
2023-03-07 17:14:43,072 139982591223616 - application INFO -
MONOMERS STATUS
(pid=12932)  cache_data_hash=d49e11e052832ed7de03f38fa61c09cabdae66473991ae3e9d02041f019983ae
(pid=12933)  cache_data_hash=d49e11e052832ed7de03f38fa61c09cabdae66473991ae3e9d02041f019983ae *****

2023-03-07 17:14:43,072 139982591223616 - uvicorn.error INFO - Application startup complete.
2023-03-07 17:14:43,072 139982591223616 - uvicorn.error INFO - Uvicorn running on socket ('127.0.0.1', 8200) (Press CTRL+C to quit)

# Then, the next day, suddenly...
2023-03-08 15:46:10,190 140122358679360 - application INFO - Connecting to: /some_path/mydatabase.db
2023-03-08 15:46:10,733 140122358679360 - application ERROR - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/some_path/my_app/web_service.py", line 74, in whitelist_authentication_and_log_all_exceptions
    if should_update_cache_data():
  File "/some_path/my_app/operations/update_cache_data.py", line 80, in should_update_cache_data
    return _should_update_cache_data(os.getpid())
  File "/some_path/my_app/operations/update_cache_data.py", line 84, in _should_update_cache_data
    cache_data_hash: Union[str, None] = _get_hash_for_pid(pid)
  File "/some_path/my_app/operations/update_cache_data.py", line 94, in _get_hash_for_pid
    cursor.execute(f"select * from {TABLE_NAME} where pid=?", (pid,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: MY_CACHE_TABLE
```

My best, weak guess is that something in my db access code, maybe combined with a concurrency issue (multi-process) is somehow breaking something -- an unclosed cursor/connection, a race condition... I've scrutinized the code as best I can. I've included all of it below.

The db is for in memory cache synchronization across multiple uvicorn processes. The single table has two columns: the PID and a hash of the cached data. When I receive a cache update notification, I update the cache for the current process, then invalidate the caches of all the other processes by setting the hash for the PID to an empty string. Each process polls the table, and if it finds an empty string for it's PID, it updates the cache and sets the new hash.

```
PID     HASH
2385    d49e11e052832ed7de03f38fa61c09cabdae66473991ae3e9d02041f019983ae
9823    d49e11e052832ed7de03f38fa61c09cabdae66473991ae3e9d02041f019983ae
```

I re-create the db every time during deployment (I never call `create_db()` or `create_table()` during runtime), and update the cache and table at startup -- there's no need to save any of the data across deployments/restarts.

```
def create_db():
    create_table()


def get_database_connection() -> sqlite3.Connection:
    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect(settings.DB_FILE_NAME)
    except sqlite3.Error as exc:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Cannot connect to {os.path.abspath(settings.DB_FILE_NAME)}") from exc

    return connection


def create_table() -> None:
    """ Establishing a connection creates the db if it doesn't exist. """
    database_connection: sqlite3.Connection = get_database_connection()
    cursor: sqlite3.Cursor

    try:
        cursor = database_connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {TABLE_NAME}")
        cursor.execute(
            f"CREATE TABLE {TABLE_NAME} (PID INTEGER, CACHE_HASH TEXT)")
    except sqlite3.Error as err:
        raise RuntimeError("Error creating database.") from err
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        database_connection.commit()
        database_connection.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_db()
```

Here is all of the other code that touches the db. Basically, I try to use the context manager (`with`) whenever possible, and otherwise try to make sure I'm committing and closing everything properly:

```
PID = 0
CACHE_DATA_HASH = 1


async def update_cache_data_and_invalidate_cache():
    result_message: dict[str, str] = await update_cache_data()
    invalidate_cache_for_all_other_processes()
    _log_cache_data_info()
    return result_message


async def update_cache_data() -> dict[str, str]:

    cache_data = await _get_cache_data()
    thin_cache_data: CacheData = CacheData(cache_data)
    cache_data_refresh_diff = len(thin_cache_data.items) - len(settings.cache_data.items)
    if len(thin_cache_data.items) > 0:
        settings.cache_data = thin_cache_data
        set_cache_data_up_to_date()
        return {"message": f"Successfully received {len(thin_cache_data.items)} items."}

    error_message: str = ("ERROR: items refresh request did not error, but we received 0 items.")
    logger.error(error_message)
    _log_cache_data_info()
    raise RuntimeError(error_message)


async def _get_cache_data() -> list[dict]:
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(verify=False) as client:
        response = await client.get(cache_data_url, timeout=15.0)
        cache_data: list[dict] = response.json()
        return cache_data


def should_update_cache_data() -> bool:
    return _should_update_cache_data(os.getpid())


def _should_update_cache_data(pid: int) -> bool:
    cache_data_hash: Union[str, None] = _get_hash_for_pid(pid, include_connection_logging=False)
    if cache_data_hash is None or cache_data_hash == '':
        return True
    return False


def _get_hash_for_pid(pid: int, include_connection_logging=True) -> Union[str, None]:
    cache_data_hash: Union[str, None] = None
    with get_database_connection(include_logging=include_connection_logging) as conn:
        cursor: sqlite3.Cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"select * from {TABLE_NAME} where pid=?", (pid,))
        result: Union[tuple, None] = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.close()

        if result is not None:
            cache_data_hash = result[CACHE_DATA_HASH]
    return cache_data_hash


def set_cache_data_up_to_date() -> None:
    current_pid: int = os.getpid()
    _set_cache_data_up_to_date(current_pid)


def _set_cache_data_up_to_date(pid: int) -> None:
    cache_data_hash: Union[str, None] = _get_hash_for_pid(pid)
    with get_database_connection() as conn:
        if cache_data_hash is None:
            conn.execute(f"insert into {TABLE_NAME} values (?, ?)", (pid, settings.cache_data.hash))
        else:
            conn.execute(
                f"update {TABLE_NAME} set cache_data_hash = ? where pid = ?", (settings.cache_data.hash, pid))


def invalidate_cache_for_all_other_processes() -> None:
    with get_database_connection() as conn:
        process_ids = []
        for row in conn.execute(f"select * from {TABLE_NAME}"):
            process_ids.append(row[PID])

        # Invalidate the cache for all other processes by setting the hash to an empty string
        this_process_pid: int = os.getpid()
        for pid in process_ids:
            if pid != this_process_pid:
                conn.execute(f"update {TABLE_NAME} set cache_data_hash = ? where pid = ?", ('', pid))


def _generate_cache_data_info() -> str:
    cache_data_info: str = "\nCACHE STATUS\n"
    got_rows: bool = False
    with get_database_connection() as conn:
        for row in conn.execute(f"select * from {TABLE_NAME}"):
            got_rows = True
            if row[PID] == os.getpid():
                cache_data_info += f"(pid={row[PID]})  cache_data_hash={row[CACHE_DATA_HASH]} *****\n"
            else:
                cache_data_info += f"(pid={row[PID]})  cache_data_hash={row[CACHE_DATA_HASH]}\n"
    if not got_rows:
        cache_data_info += f"{TABLE_NAME} is empty."
    return cache_data_info


def _log_cache_data_info() -> None:
    logger.info(_generate_cache_data_info())
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be because the SQLite db file was on an NFS filesystem. I'm not sure exactly what was happening to the db file, but it was getting "corrupted" because of concurrent access:

> SQLite uses reader/writer locks to control access to the database.... But use caution: this locking mechanism might not work correctly if the database file is kept on an NFS filesystem.

https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5